# Dragging objects out of an IFrame

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have an IFrame on my page pointing to a page containing list of `<li />` elements. The `<li />` elements are [Draggables](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/draggable) created using [Scriptaculous library](http://script.aculo.us/).

The question is how do I drag the elements OUT of the IFrame, and drop them on the page containing the IFrame?

Is there any library available which supports cross frame dragging & dropping? I don't know about jQuery, but Scriptaculous definitely doesn't support this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this [interesting implementation](http://www.bluestudios.co.uk/blog/sandbox/iframe/iframe.html), it was done using PrototypeJS and Scriptaculous

I find this workaround interesting since it actually uses two iframes that contain LI items, and you can drag and drop between the iframes.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, [here](http://www.bluestudios.co.uk/blog/?p=216)'s another demo from the same site that makes dragging (dropping not implemented however) out of an external site from within an iframe possible.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible as far as I know. The way iframes are implemented in browsers that would be like dragging and dropping page elements from one window to another.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible in HTML5, but it's not widely implemented yet, and it's only a draft. You can google for some information on it, or play around with a demo I found. You should be able to rewrite it to work with iframes.

[Demo](http://ljouanneau.com/lab/html5/demodragdrop.html)

[Specifications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#dnd)